# Can the volts and\or amps in a repalcement DC power cord vary without problems?

Tags: power-supply, dc

In general I've always wondered about this but now I have lost the DC power cord to my portable speakers.  The manufacture does not have a replacement or at least one I can find.  The specs are 12.5 V --- 2.5a.

Questions:

1) If I buy a generic replacement which of the voltage and amps need to match and\or if I can't get an exact match how can I vary the volts\amps ... which can I go higher or lower on.

So for example would 12 volts and 5 amps work, be harmful, or not work\not work well?

2) Do voltage\amps have some standardization on the input adapter into the device?  That is, will I also need to ensure a generic replacement also matches the portable speakers or should it just match if the voltage\amps match?

GB

p.s. I think this is the stack exchange I should be  posting this to if not please advise.

Comment: Have you lost the cable that connects power supply to the speakers, or have you lost the entire DC power supply?

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed in many previous posts, and I really should find a link, rather than answering it once again...

The voltage of the new supply must match the voltage required by your device.

The current rating of the new supply must equal or exceed the demand of the load.  The current rating on a power supply is the maximum current it is designed to deliver, but it won't force that current into the load - the load will only take the current it requires.

Comment: It should also match polarity. Most power supplies allow the user to change the polarity.